# Pandas adding dataframe to another dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Horses':["Horse1","Horse2","Horse3"],
        'Age':[2,5,3],
        'Price':["$100,000","$80,000","$60,000"],
        'Weight':["180g","140kg","240kg"]})  

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Horses':["Horse4","Horse1","Horse5"],
        'Age':[4,3,2],
        'Price':["$75,000","$35,000","$120,000"],
        'Weight':["210kg","110kg","197kg"]})  



df_final = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Horses':["Horse1","Horse2","Horse3","Horse4","Horse5"],
        'Age':[2,5,3,4,2],
        'Price':["$100,000","$80,000","$60,000","$75,000","$120,000"],
        'Weight':["180g","140kg","240kg","210kg","197kg"]})
```

- How can I  create the df_final  DataFrame from the first two DataFrames bf_1 and bf_2 ?
- How can I code this condition:
  If "Horse1" is input it is erased like above, else it is added in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `combine_first`

```
df_1.set_index('Horses',inplace=True)
df_1=df_1.combine_first(df_2.set_index('Horses')).reset_index()
df_1
   Horses  Age     Price Weight
0  Horse1  2.0  $100,000   180g
1  Horse2  5.0   $80,000  140kg
2  Horse3  3.0   $60,000  240kg
3  Horse4  4.0   $75,000  210kg
4  Horse5  2.0  $120,000  197kg
```

Comment: What if "Horse1" in df_2 can be input to "Horse6" and I want my program to deal with both cases in a single script ? Edit:When "Horse1" is input it is erased like above,  else it is added in the bottom.

Comment: So this is different question then @AnisBenna, I will suggest close this question and open a new one (If you think my answer help you with the current question, you can accept it check mark at the right )

Comment: Okay even if only it helped partially. The part about the condition is mentioned but only briefly. Edit:Updated

Comment: @AnisBenna I think it is better open a new one and close this one . It is depends on you

Comment: @AnisBenna also if you think the answer help you , you can always select one of them to accept, check mark at the left.